# repopulating rows of data from a table in excel from searching a specific field

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, vba

Simple excel question.

I have a table consisting of for example (Name, Job, Country, etc)

I want to be able to search firstly the table for rows of data containing for example "Brazil"  from the country column.

so in the end

it should populate in the format like below

ben   engineer   brazil
ken   lawyer     brazil

If you guys could give me an example of how to write the formula it would be great. Some of you guys might suggest filtering but my intentions are to splice the data.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you "searching" for Brazil?
Filtering? Where would you like the results? in a different place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My table:

```
Date        id  country job
05.02.2016  2   braz    ing
10.02.2016  4   ger     chem
07.02.2016  3   franc   bio
11.05.2016  5   braz    chem
```

I wrote a little sub to search for a string. It is hardcoded but you don't have to start on an empty page. Now you have to make it dynamically and adjust it to your problem/needs.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'variables
Dim search As Range
Dim Txt As String
Dim counter As Integer

'The text for which to search -> implement eg. an inputBox
Txt = "braz"
'counter to print the matches
counter = 1

'loop over number of rows -> implement a variable LastRow
For i = 1 To 5
    'column hardcoded -> 3 (country)
    If Cells(i, 3).Value = Txt Then
            'copy whole row and past to F1:I1 for the first match and
            'F2:I2 for the second and so on (counter)
            Range("A" & i & ":D" & i).Copy Range("F" & counter & ":I" & counter)
            counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: you can work with InputBoxes or you can create a UserForm to handle the input